# Define Products in Controller using a Model defined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hello I'm trying to call specific products in a controller:

products_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @products = Product.where(:active => true)
end
```

And update that index method using this from the product_decorator.rb:

```
def purchase(from_date, to_date)
   LineItem.select('product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity_sold')
   .where({orders: {state: 'complete', completed_at: from_date..to_date}})
   .group(:product_id).inject({}) {|h, l| h[l.product_id] = l.quantity_sold; h}
end
```

(this returns the purchase count for each product)

So that the new products_controller.rb index would read:

```
def index
    @products = Product.where(:active => true).where.purchase(Date.today-365,Date.today).count > 1
end
```

To only show 'purchased' products.  The '.where.purchase(Date...' is where I am totally lost, as I don't know how to use a helper method to query against in a controller.

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the `purchase` method as either a class method or a scope, i.e. one of the following:

**product.rb**

```
def self.purchase(from_date, to_date)
   LineItem.select('product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity_sold')
           .where({orders: {state: 'complete', completed_at: from_date..to_date}})
           .group(:product_id).inject({}) {|h, l| h[l.product_id] = l.quantity_sold; h}
end
```

Or:

```
scope :purchase, (from_date, to_date) ->  { 
  LineItem.select('product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity_sold')
          .where({orders: {state: 'complete', completed_at: from_date..to_date}})
          .group(:product_id).inject({}) {|h, l| h[l.product_id] = l.quantity_sold; h}
}
```

Then you'll be able to call this on a collection of records, using:

```
@products = Product.where(:active => true).purchase(Date.today-365,Date.today).count > 1
```

That covers the issue you're facing in the question. Does that help?

I've not had a look at the actual code in the methods (and would consider adjusting the naming to something clearer), but this should get you in the right direction.

If you run into subsequent issues, pop in a new question and feel free to give me a shout :)